# How does a typical RDBMS store and locate blocks?

Tags: database, io, rdbms

I understand that the block is the fundamental physical element of an FS and DBMS. How does a relational database management system, like MySQL or Oracle, store its block data and later load it into memory? Does it use the file system? A search method? Or just bare I/O like a file system?

I've searched everywhere for the answer and haven't found the answer, although I'm sure block storage is something many would have to know about, looking at the number of implementations.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Just to clarify, what I want to know is how the DBMS actually implements this block in storage. Does it use file system clusters or bypass the FS altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know nothing about how MySQL and Oracle store data, however I can give a bit of insight into how Microsoft SQL Server works

In SQL Server the fundamental unit of storage is a Page which is 8 KB in size.  Everything is stored in page sized chunks and pretty much all of the memory is also organised and allocated in these 8 KB chunks.  For example all of the following is stored in pages:

- The data in tables
- Indexes
- Execution plans

Whenever a page is being used it **must** be loaded into memory and kept loaded until SQL Server has finished working with that page, however when the work is complete it isn't just discarded, instead SQL Server tries to buffer as many pages in memory as possible and so the page instead lives in the buffer pool - a list of pages that are still in memory however are available for repurposing if needed (discarding and then being used when accessing a different page).

SQL Server keeps track of what pages are available in the buffer pool to avoid reading from or writing to the disk whenever possible - there are a complex set of rules govorning when a page is repurposed (including "lazy writing" any dirty pages to disk should any changes have been made) in order to try and keep frequently used pages in memory and minimise cache misses.  Basically SQL Server is constantly trying to use as much memory as it can without triggering OS page faults.

As for how it knows which pages to load this is mostly down indexing - Indexes (which are also stored in pages) are structured in such a way that SQL Server is able to traverse through the index and find the relevant record in the index (depending on the query) with a minimal number of reads.  The index then contains links informing SQL Server which pages contain the actual data.

This is a massive over simplification, however should at least give a rough overview of how things work.  If you are interested in learning more then I recommend the [Wikipedia page on SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#Data_storage), in particular the "Data Storage" section.  There are also a number of books on the internals of SQL Server which I found to be very informative.